# Unscape characters (metacharacters and accents)

Tags: javascript, escaping

My program is consuming data from an API which returns something like this:

```
"<a href=\"http:\/\/www.website2.com\/\" target=\"_blank\">Item card<\/a>","<img src=\"https:\/\/website.com\/assets\/images\/flags\/es.png\">","81","80","63","65","62","38933",700,"<a class=\"btn btn-warning  btn-sm\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#info20\"><i class=\"fa fa-eye\"><\/i> Ver<\/a><a class=\"btn btn-success btn-sm\"  data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#buy20\"><i class=\"fa fa-shopping-cart\"><\/i> Comprar<\/a><div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"info20\" aria-hidden=\"true\"><div class=\"modal-dialog modal-lg\">\n              <div class=\"modal-content\">\n                <div class=\"modal-header\">\n                  <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-hidden=\"true\"><i class=\"icons-office-52\"><\/i><\/button>\n                  <h4 class=\"modal-title\"><strong>Mas informaci\u00f3n<\/strong><\/h4>\n                <\/div>\n                <div class=\"modal-body\">\n"]
```

Notice it's not only scaping `"` and `/`, but also special characters.

And I would like to convert it to normal HTML. **Is there any vanilla JavaScript function to achieve it?**

Comment: Which special characters do you refer to?

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @Bergi Example of special character: `\u00f3` (ó). And `JSON.parse` does not work.

Comment: Are you sure it's escaping them? This could be a *representation* of the data you are seeing. If you do `console.log("<a href=\"http:\/\/www.website2.com\/\" target=\"_blank\">Item card<\/a>")` you will see the correct data

Comment: @JohnRodríguez What error do you get when you use `JSON.parse`? Or maybe the JSON is already parsed? What exactly does the API respond with, and how do you call it?

Answer (score -1):

Simple `unescape(response)` should do the job of unescaping special characters - then you can go on to use it with any method which takes html code as input (like `insertAdjacentHTML`)

Comment: Doesn't (deprecated) `unescape` method unescape hex escape sequences ("percent code") instead of escape characters ..?

Comment: It unescapes both